# Need to Remove the extra space below the rich:menuItem

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I have added 1 rich:menuItem inside rich:dropDownMenu. but in the UI there is a extra space below the menuItem. how to remove that space.

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox browser with the Firebug addon and inspect the element on your page.

Chances are it's a CSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of issue. I've modified the `rich-menu-list-strut` CSS class to set its `height` to `0`:

```
.rich-menu-list-strut {
    height: 0;
}
```